# Searching String with double quotes in awk

Tags: regex, shell, unix, awk, double-quotes

I have a huge file dat file(comma separated). In which I have to replace 2nd column with "foo"(with double quotes, if 3rd column has value starting with "AB(with quote)

Here is the sample input.dat

```
"5000","ABC","AB8989"
"3000","   ","AB7676"
"2000","   ","A07444"
"4000","   ","BN0909"
```

This is the command I am using:

```
awk -F, -vOFS=, '{if($3 ~/^"AB/){$2="foo"}print;}' input.dat
```

This command ideally should match only 1st two rows, but I don't know why it is matching the 3rd line also. Looks like it is not reading B after A in reg ex. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks fine for me (I have shorten it some), what system are you on?

```
awk -F, -vOFS=, '$3 ~/^"AB/{$2="\"foo\""}1' input.dat
"5000","foo","AB8989"
"3000","foo","AB7676"
"2000","   ","A07444"
"4000","   ","BN0909"
```

PS I added double quotes to `"foo"`

Comment: I am using HP-unix. If I dont have to compare double quotes then it is matching AB. But with double quote only A is checked.

Comment: I have accidentally written ^"AB* in regex in my script. ^"AB is working fine. But why ^"AB* is allowing "A0?

Comment: `B*` does mean `0` or more `B` so it would match A, AB, ABB, ABBB etc